# Python: Two parse statements not working together

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

In sql column names are given along with table they belong to i.e; in this way- emp.ename or just the column name ename.
I'm writing a program to parse these kind of sql statements using PyParsing library.
rc1 is the for without table name convention and rc2 for the other.

```
rc1=delimitedList(column_name("columns*") + Optional(Optional(AS) + column_alias("col_alias*"))) + (ZeroOrMore(delimitedList(rc2)))

rc2= OneOrMore(delimitedList(("tab") + "." + column_name("Source_Columns") + Optional(Optional(AS) + column_alias)))

result_column = "*" | OneOrMore(delimitedList(table_name("tab") + "." + column_name("Source_Columns") + Optional(Optional(AS) + column_alias("col_alias"))))| OneOrMore(rc1) |OneOrMore(rc2)|OneOrMore(rc1+rc2)|OneOrMore(rc2+rc1)

select_core = (SELECT + Optional(DISTINCT | ALL) + OneOrMore(result_column) +
                Optional(FROM + join_source("from*"))
```

In result_column both are read. I gave all the combinations rc1+rc2, rc2+rc1..
Suppose my 1st input query is:

```
SELECT emp.ename as e FROM scott.employee as emp
```

Output is:

```
{'tab': 'emp', 'Source_Columns': 'ename', 'col_alias': 'e', 'table_alias': 'emp', 'from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}
```

2nd input:

```
SELECT ename as e, fname as f FROM scott.employee as emp
```

output:

```
{'columns': 'ename    fname', 'col_alias': 'e    f', 'table_alias': 'emp', 'from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}
```

3rd input: (Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc2+rc1)

```
SELECT emp.eid, fname,lname FROM scott.employee as emp
```

Output:

```
{'tab': 'emp', 'Source_Columns': 'eid'}
```

4th input: (Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc1+rc2)

```
SELECT ename, lname, emp.eid FROM scott.employee as emp
```

Output:

```
{'columns': 'ename    lname    emp'}
```

I hope you understand  my problem from these I/O
The 3rd output should have been something like this: {'tab': 'emp', `'Source_Columns': 'eid', 'columns':'fname lname','from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}`
and the 4th one: `{'columns': 'ename    lname ','tab': 'emp', 'Source_Columns': 'eid',from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}`

What am I missing? (outputs can be seen using `select_core.runTests(tests)` and input can be given as a string in `tests` )

Comment: Unless you're doing this for exercise's sake, I suggest looking into https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If you are using runTests, it is probably easier to just post the output, which echoes each input test before dumping out the parsed results. You can even annotate your tests with '#' comments, and the comments will be echoed with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your tests laid out for runTests:

```
tests = """\
SELECT emp.ename as e FROM scott.employee as emp
SELECT ename as e, fname as f FROM scott.employee as emp
#Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc2+rc1)
SELECT emp.eid, fname,lname FROM scott.employee as emp
#Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc1+rc2)
SELECT ename, lname, emp.eid FROM scott.employee as emp
"""
```

Using the parser from select_parser.py, runTests output is:

```
SELECT emp.ename as e FROM scott.employee as emp
['SELECT', [['emp.ename', 'AS', 'e']], 'FROM', ['scott', '.', 'employee'], 'AS', 'emp']
- columns: [['emp.ename', 'AS', 'e']]
  [0]:
    ['emp.ename', 'AS', 'e']
- from: [['scott', '.', 'employee']]
  [0]:
    ['scott', '.', 'employee']
    - database: ['scott']
    - table: [['employee']]
      [0]:
        ['employee']
- table_alias: [['emp']]
  [0]:
    ['emp']


SELECT ename as e, fname as f FROM scott.employee as emp
['SELECT', [['ename', 'AS', 'e'], ['fname', 'AS', 'f']], 'FROM', ['scott', '.', 'employee'], 'AS', 'emp']
- columns: [['ename', 'AS', 'e'], ['fname', 'AS', 'f']]
  [0]:
    ['ename', 'AS', 'e']
  [1]:
    ['fname', 'AS', 'f']
- from: [['scott', '.', 'employee']]
  [0]:
    ['scott', '.', 'employee']
    - database: ['scott']
    - table: [['employee']]
      [0]:
        ['employee']
- table_alias: [['emp']]
  [0]:
    ['emp']

#Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc2+rc1)
SELECT emp.eid, fname,lname FROM scott.employee as emp
['SELECT', [['emp.eid'], ['fname'], ['lname']], 'FROM', ['scott', '.', 'employee'], 'AS', 'emp']
- columns: [['emp.eid'], ['fname'], ['lname']]
  [0]:
    ['emp.eid']
  [1]:
    ['fname']
  [2]:
    ['lname']
- from: [['scott', '.', 'employee']]
  [0]:
    ['scott', '.', 'employee']
    - database: ['scott']
    - table: [['employee']]
      [0]:
        ['employee']
- table_alias: [['emp']]
  [0]:
    ['emp']

#Here I combine both conventions i.e' rc1+rc2)
SELECT ename, lname, emp.eid FROM scott.employee as emp
['SELECT', [['ename'], ['lname'], ['emp.eid']], 'FROM', ['scott', '.', 'employee'], 'AS', 'emp']
- columns: [['ename'], ['lname'], ['emp.eid']]
  [0]:
    ['ename']
  [1]:
    ['lname']
  [2]:
    ['emp.eid']
- from: [['scott', '.', 'employee']]
  [0]:
    ['scott', '.', 'employee']
    - database: ['scott']
    - table: [['employee']]
      [0]:
        ['employee']
- table_alias: [['emp']]
  [0]:
    ['emp']
```

These shouldn't really be two different statements in pyparsing, you should be able to write just one what captures an optional leading table name, and give it an appropriate results name. Then make the column name a group so that name and table can be extracted from each one.

Comment: After posting this, I reviewed the select_parser.py example in the pyparsing examples directory, and have made some minor refinements, and added your examples to the list of tests. Please give that a look.

Comment: Also, this is largely a duplicate of your previous question, please continue further efforts there.

Comment: @PaulMG Yes I posted it twice instead of editing. My mistake! Can you please remove this as duplicate so that I can delete the other one?

Comment: @PaulMG col, col_tab all of them are now string value of columns key, Is there a way where I can separately retrieve them ?That is not as a huge string value but separate key value pairs of their own. Simple way of just getting the value `selr.col_tab`  doesn't work.

Comment: This is what Group will do for you. Group the (table + '.' + column) expression and drop the '*'s from the results names. Then results names won't bleed over from one column to the next. You'll have to iterate over them all to get the list of all tables though.

Comment: I didn't get it. This is was I'm trying: input: `SELECT lname,e.ename,f.fname  FROM scott.employee as emp` I'm making a dictionary of all the parsed values. This is what I get: `{'columns': 'lname     {col_tab:  e   col:  ename }    {col_tab:  f   col:  fname }', 'table_alias': 'emp', 'from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}` wHAT I'm asking for is to simply have different keys but I can't take them out. This is what I'm expecting: `{'columns': 'lname  ename   fname', 'col_tab':'e  f' ,'table_alias': 'emp', 'from': '{database:  scott   table:   employee  }'}` Pls help me out here!

Comment: The values you want are all there. The column names can be had using (assuming you have assigned the parsed data to a variable named "result) `[col.col for col in result.columns[`. tables as `[col.col_tab for col in result.columns[`. and so on. The parsing part is done, the rest is just python extraction of data from a dict. If you would rather work with a dict than a ParseResults, use `result.asDict()` - then you will need to use `result_dict["columns"]` notation.